# Find and Replace string in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a CSV file containing three columns:

```
10.630892, 43.653193,This is a GPS position 
10.630893, 43.653194,This is a GPS position of a restaurant 
10.630895, 43.653195,This is a GPS position of a very nice restaurant
```

I would like to have the following result :

```
10.630892, 43.653193,Restaurant
10.630893, 43.653194,Restaurant
10.630895, 43.653195,Restaurant
```

In other words , whatever is after the second coma(till the end of the line) , to be replaced with a given word , for example : `Restaurant`

I tried to identify the string `",This is"` followed by no matter how many characters and replace with `",Restaurant"` , but still unsuccessful ...

Comment: What do you mean "but still unsuccessful"? You exactly described one way how you can find the string you are attempting to remove. Show the actual code and language you are attempting to find/replace in, and then we can possibly explain what error or mistake you are getting.

Comment: It's tagged Notepad++...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this with Notepad++, I would just open up the CSV file in Excel*, replace the third column all the way down, and save as CSV again.

* Or any other spreadsheet program that can read and save CSVs.

Comment: Thank you Richard, I forgot how powerful is excel :) . Because I have several words in 3rd column which I want to replace with a single word , this approach is the fastest . Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know what you mean. My first thought was "Could I do this with Awk?" Then I realized, "He said Notepad++! That means Windows..." and that's when Excel popped into my mind. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should tick the regular expression box, and try to search `,This is.*$` and replace it with `,Restaurant`.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace Dialog.

Under search mode, select Regular Expression.

- Find what: ,T.*
- Replace with: ,Restaurant
- Click on Replace all